# Jasper - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Jaspersoft Studio 6.5.1.final and compatibility with JasperReport 4.7.0

I am getting this error in JasperStudio while trying to run the report on JasperServer due to some unknown reason. I have no elements in any report files with the name 'property' so narrowing this down has been difficult.

Full stack trace:

```
    java.lang.Exception: The Server has returned an error with code 1 and with the
message org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.runReport(WSClient.java:421)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.soap.SoapConnection.runReport(SoapConnection.java:416)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.runReport(ProxyConnection.java:412)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.runReportUnit(WSClientHelper.java:464)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.editor.ReportRunControler$2.run(ReportRunControler.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Compiling the report does not work but does not return any errors or show up in the Error Log. This report was working a couple weeks ago and no changes have been made to the report or any subreports inside of it.

Comment: You are using version of *jrxml* created with help of JasperReports (created with help of IDE or manual created using xsd from library) of version differ from version of JR Server

Comment: @AlexK isn't that what setting compatibility mode is supposed to fix? If not, what can be done to fix it? The duplicate you linked has custom Java code and is very far from my situation.

Comment: `The duplicate you linked has custom Java code and is very far from my situation` - Maybe not, maybe yes. You did not even post the code. `If not, what can be done to fix it?` - 1) You can check the content of file manually - you can validate content with xsd. 2) You can create small *jxml* and repeat the same steps - mabye you are missing something or using the wrong file 3) You can create small Java project and try to compile *jrxml* with help of code using the same version of JasperReports library

Comment: @AlexK sorry I'm not using any Java code here at all. I'll try validating the XML. I might just delete the report and start from scratch, my other reports are working fine.

Comment: Yes, it can be a small typo

Comment: @AlexK the XML is good, no errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178885/discussion-between-star-trac-and-alex-k).